# Log4j not writing logs to database

Tags: java, log4j

I need to log errors for my application to database. I added the following in log4j.xml
Database logs are not getting written to tables, but I could see log messages on my console.

What could be the reason for this. My database connect string details are correct.

log4j.xml

```
  <appender name="jdbcAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender"> 
        <param name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:test" /> 
        <param name="Driver" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" /> 
        <param name="User" value="scott" /> 
        <param name="Password" value="tiger" /> 
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
            <param name="ConversionPattern" 
              value="INSERT INTO my_table (log_date, log_level, location, message) VALUES ( '%d{ISO8601}','%p',
              '%C;%L', '%m' )" 
            /> 
        </layout> 
    </appender> 
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
            <param name="ConversionPattern" 
              value="%d{ISO8601} %p (%C;%L) %m%n" 
            /> 
        </layout> 
    </appender> 
    <logger name="logging.simple.jdbcLogger" additivity="true">
        <level value="info"/> 
        <appender-ref ref="jdbcAppender"/> 
    </logger> 
    <root> 
        <level value="info"/> 
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/> 
    </root> 
</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll see log messages on the console because you've sent *all* log messages to the console, but only loggers under the hierarchy of `logging.simple.jdbcLogger` are sent to `jdbcAppender`.

Do you see `logging.simple.jdbcLogger` messages on the console?

Comment: I cannot find logging.simple.jdbcLogger. But level I have given as info for both console and jdbcAppender!

Comment: that isn't how log4j works. Each log4j logger has a name, and with this configuration, only loggers in your code whose name starts with "logging.simple.jdbcLogger" will be sent to the `jdbcAppender`

Comment: @matt b Oh I see. I have the following in my class Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName().toString()); Do I need to add any additional to get it logged to database?

Comment: using the name of the class, you should add something to the log4j configuration for it. For example if your class is named `matt.dao.FooDao`, perhaps you want to add `<logger name="matt.dao"><appender-ref ref="jdbcAppender"/>..`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is working fine. However I do have one issue which is nothing but when it is writing logs to database, it is not geting displayed in console. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: I managed to get that working as well. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Add `<appender-ref ref="jdbcAppender"/>` to the `<root>...</root>` section.